# File is empty after downloading

Tags: perl, download, cgi

I am trying to download csv file from server. File is getting downloaded however it is empty. Any suggestions are highly welcome. Filename is Maintenance_File.csv which is present in /home/netcool location.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI ':standard';
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $files_location;
my $ID;
my @fileholder;

$files_location = "/home/netcool";

#$ID = param('file');
$ID = "Maintenance_File.csv";
#print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
#print "ID =$ID";

if ($ID eq '') {
  print "You must specify a file to download.";
} else {
  $fileloc="/home/netcool/" . $ID;
  open(DLFILE, "$fileloc") || Error('open', 'file');
  @fileholder = <DLFILE>;
  close (DLFILE) || Error ('close', 'file');
  #print "Files data = @fileholder";
  print "Content-Type:application/octet-stream;\n";
  print "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=\"$ID\"\r\n\n";
  print @fileholder
  #open(DLFILE, "< $fileloc") || Error('open', 'file');
  #while(read(DLFILE, $buffer, 100) ) {
  #  print("$buffer");
  #}
  #close (DLFILE) || Error ('close', 'file');

}
```

Comment: When I set this up on a new installation of Ubuntu and made a couple of tiny tweaks (because I don't have a file called `/home/netcool/Maintenance_File.csv`), it worked exactly as expected. The problem is, therefore, in something that you don't show us. What system are you running this on? Is anything being written to the web server error log?

Comment: I mean, there are all sorts of improvements to the code that I could suggest (why aren't you using `use strict` and `use warnings`? why load CGI.pm and then not use it? why are you writing CGI programs in 2019?) but, basically, this approach works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works. I don't know why it doesn't work in your environment, but it works as expected on mine. Perhaps you could share some more information about the environment you're running it on.

- What operating system are you using?
- What web server are you using?
- Is anything written to the web server error log?

Your code uses a number of rather dated constructs. Rewritten to more modern Perl, it looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI 'header';
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $files_location = "/home/netcool";

my $filename = 'Maintenance_File.csv';

if (!$filename) {
  die "You must specify a file to download";
  exit;
}

print header(
  -type => 'application/octet-stream',
  -content_disposition => "attachment;filename=$filename",
);

my $fileloc = "$files_location/$filename";
open my $fh, '<', $fileloc or Error('open', 'file', $!);
print while <$fh>;
close $fh or Error ('close', 'file' );

sub Error {
  die "@_";
}
```

But none of my edits change the fundamental working of your code. I assume that my version will fail in the same way as your original one.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Cross for your comment. The code is working now accept for the below change.  print header(
  -type => 'text/csv',
  -content_disposition => "attachment;filename=$filename",
);

Comment: Now if suppose I have give two textboxes on the webpage and based on the inputs ,need to form the filename and then go for download.The below code is not working

Comment: my $files_location = "/home/netcool";
my $first = $cgi->param('first_name');
my $last = $cgi->param('last_name');
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print <<EndOfHTML;
<html><head><title>Generating Self-Referential URLs</title></head>
<body>
<FORM action="Maintenance_Data.cgi" method="POST">
Circle: <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br>
Technology: <input type="text" name="last_name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</FORM>
</body>
EndOfHTML my $filename = $first . '_' . $last .'.csv';

Comment: @SaurabhJain: If someone has answered your question then you should accept their answer. If you have a follow-up question, then please ask it in a new post.